# Boostrap and DropDown and Nav-tabs Bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar, adminlte

I am using Admin LTE Theme 2.3 and have this bug only in DropDown and Nav-tabs

[image: DropDown Is active bug Nav-tabs is active too]

If i have remove theme, no have any problem.

Soryy for my bad english

Comment: have you add z-index in navigation bar?

Comment: No Nirav, how proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this. `.nav-bar .nav-item {z-index: 1}` this for navigation and `.dropdown .dropdown-menu {z-index: 999}`

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
>
> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

But you have to match your classes in theme. it's just an example so don't put this same classes in your `css` file.

Try this. Hope it will helps you. :)